# I have six images and on hover how can I reveal one large image?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

What I am trying to do is reveal one of six larger images when you mouse over any of six smaller images.

The large image would be made up of the six smaller placeholders.

The attached image shows a couple examples of what I am trying to do.

Thanks for any answers on this.

[image]

Comment: Some code would be quite helpful. If you could post the html in each state or create a jsfiddle we could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really proud of this but it does what you ask.

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/N4aFP/2/

```
var srcs;

srcs = new Array();

var i = 0;

$('img').each(function(){

    srcs[i] = $(this).attr('src');

    i++;
});

$('img').hover(function(){

    $('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
},function(){

    restore(srcs);
});

function restore(srcs) {

    i = 0;

    $('img').each(function(){

        $(this).attr('src', srcs[i]);

        i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response... How does your answer differ from this one: http://jsfiddle.net/vkAbg/2/ I'm not sure which is the best solution...

Comment: Looks like that one is putting the images into a new object `more-images` and then overlaying it onto the page.  So you have a 1-6 layer, then a N x 6 layer that appears on top.  Mine just replaces the src attribute, so you only have 6 images and no hokey pokey

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vkAbg/

```
$('#images img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#more-images img').remove();
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        $('#more-images').append($(this).clone());
    }
});
```

Here's an updated example with a few more images: http://jsfiddle.net/vkAbg/1/

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, here's an update with what seems more like your requirement:

http://jsfiddle.net/vkAbg/2/

Comment: @sg3s: because the OP wants a jQuery solution.

Comment: +1 Good idea to put the hover image below / next to the thumbnails instead of on top of them as the OP will run into serious usability problems.

Comment: Jamie thanks for your response.. The only thing is, I need the two sides to exist in the same space... If you look at my graphic, State 1 and State 2 are in the same space. So when you hover over image 1, all six images would turn revealing one large image.

Comment: @mm-93 Please see my update. Let me know if this is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update... How does your's differ from imoda's above? I'm not sure which would be the best to use...

Comment: You already accepted imodas answer so I guess that solves that mystery :)

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/awy8F/6/

Look at how I added one image, your image, to that one class, making sure that it is only applied to the first square.

This should help you right? It's simply changing the css position of the background image...

Comment: What is this?  It's not even a partial solution.

Comment: I didn't save the jsfiddle :-/

Comment: This should probably be deleted until you get it updated with a real answer.